# 10 element array

Tags: c, arrays

My teacher gave an assignment to me. The question is below:=

Write a program that prompts the user to enter 10 double numbers. The program should accomplish the follwing:

a. Store the information in a 10-element array.
b. Display the 10 numbers back to the user.

I could do all of the above in main().

Hint: You should use loops, not hardcode the values 0 through 9. It should be easy to convert your program to accept 1000 numbers instead of 10.

For a bonus mark, do at least one of the tasks (a or b) in a separate function. Pass the array to the function; do NOT use global (extern) variables.

I confused above. I wrote a program in the source code. Am I doing wrong? It is below:=

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

   int number[10];               
   int i;   

   for (i = 0; i <10; i++)                 
     printf("%d.\n", i, number[i]);        

   printf("\n\nPress [Enter] to exit program.\n");

   fflush(stdin);
   getchar();

   return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This program doesn't prompt the user to enter 10 double numbers

Comment: first, you need to include the language (c/c++/etc) you are working with, and when asking for homework help, include the homework tag.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: I suggest you review how you input numbers in C. Then write a program that prompts for a single number, inputs it and prints it. Once that works, modify it to use an array.

Comment: This may sound harsh, but get out your textbook and use it. Additionally, read the question and ask yourself the following questions: "Did I include a prompt?" (No) "Did I store 10 numbers?" (No) "Did I display the 10 numbers I stored?" (No) "Do I know what a function is?" If you answer all of these with a "Yes" odds are you will be done with a finished assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Not too bad so far, I'd like to make the following comments:

- if you need to input double numbers, you should probably use `double` rather than `int`.
- you need a statement (maybe in your current loop but possibly in another loop preceding the current one) which inputs the numbers. Look into `scanf` for this.
- Using `%d` with `printf` is for integers, not doubles. You will have hopefully already figured out the format string to used when you looked into `scanf` above.
- Bravo for using the correct `int main(void)` form and for not including `conio.h` :-)

Once you've figured those bits out, then you can worry about doing it in a separate function.

Comment: You missed "Don't use `fflush(stdin)` " :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have given above, I would suggest reading up on the following:

1. scanf
2. functions in C, particularly passing arrays to functions: this [link](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap7/section2.1.2.html) should be good.

Note to OP: If you were able to do (a) and (b) in main(), the code above is not complete. It would be nice the functions you created for getting (a) and (b) above done for getting to the root of your "confusion".

Let me know in case you need more help.

HTH,
Sriram

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's C Primer Plus(fifth edition) but not C++. I looked for "separate function" in the book, but there is nothing. What is separate function?

Comment: @Ahsan: Just as printf and scanf are functions, your teacher wants you to write code that allows the user to enter and print 10 numbers. There is no such thing as "separate functions", at least not in C/C++. You can take a look at this link here: http://www.functionx.com/cpp/Lesson05.htm This is a nice introduction to functions and should get you started. Do not hesitate to ask more questions. I think it is better if you were to solve the question on your own, will help in the long run. And I will help you out.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it may sloves your problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

   double number[10];               
   int i;   
printf("Enter double numbers:");
   for (i = 0; i <10; i++)                 
     scanf("%lf",&number[i] );        

printf("The numbers you entered are:");

   for (i = 0; i <10; i++)                 
     printf("%lf\n",number[i] );        


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not downvote complete code answers. In my mind this is contra-productive.

Comment: That's a matter of interpretation usually, @InsertNickHere. It's not helpful to post complete code answers for homework questions since it spoonfeeds learners and harms them in the long run. I'll do that if they specifically ask for a solution rather than just help but I think the operative part here was "Am I doing wrong?".